# Rewriting URLs inside of Alfresco

Tags: tomcat6, alfresco

I'm doing something similar to what was asked here:

[Tomcat URL Rewrite Filter isn't forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438669/tomcat-url-rewrite-filter-isnt-forwarding)

Though I'm indifferent what mechanism I use. However, lets assume someone goes to my instance of Alfresco using this URL:

website/share/doc.php?id=123

I would like to have that URL be rewritten to something valid. I have a webscript that will take in the URL, process the ID, and convert it to a working Alfreso Share URL, but I can't seem to get the any rewrite mechanism working. Alfresco Share uses UrlRewriteFilter (tuckey.org), and I added the following to share's web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And then to urlrewrite.xml: (for now just doing a proof of concept)

```
<rule>
   <from>/doc.php?id=(.*)</form>
   <to>/page/repository</to>
</rule>
```

However, I wasn't able to get the URL to be rewritten. I also tested out some of the other URL rewrites specified in the urlrewrite.xml file, and it didn't look like Alfresco was doing rewrite, even though there were rules for them (ex: /feedservice/ doesn't appear to be rewritten to /page/feed/ when I click the RSS Feed button on the Repository pages).

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of rewrite is implemented using the forward method of RequestDispatcher for incoming links and not a redirect. Hence the rewritten URL does not appear for the client. You should be able to tell whether it is working by verifying the servlet mapping for the rewritten URL kicks in. I think you can also set the loglevel of tuckey so you see what it does.